# JDBC Interactive Connection

Tags: mysql, jdbc, birt

I believe I am not the first one who have encountered this problem so I am here.
Problem is with Birt (a reporting tool) reports which we show on our website.

Following are two MySQL configuration variables which we studied in details:

[wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

[interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

Basically setting `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` to default value which is eight hours can lead our database server to run out of available connection or speed issues in production environment. Our application is running on a non-interactive client (Apache/PHP).

> The interactive timeout does not affect any web application
>   connections. A high interactive_timeout but a low wait_timeout is
>   normal and is the best practice.

Based on above observation we tried setting wait_timeout = 60 and interactive_timeout = 3600  on MySQL server and also added extra parameters to enforce a INTERACTIVE_CLIENT connection via following connection URL when publishing Birt reports. Birt uses [mysql-java-connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) to connect with MySql:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.178.192.135:3306/ChapmanB_vkjUZSr?interactiveClient=true&useCompression=true&autoReconnect=true&initialTimeout=3600&maxReconnects=10
```

But we still getting connection aborted error in MySql logs. It looks like `interactiveClient=true` parameter is not effective and still creating non-interactive connection. When we increase `wait_timeout` value we do not get error for a longer time. Based on `wait_timeout = 60` MySQL automatically closes the idle connection in specified time, when Birt tries to reuse that connection, reports does not work on first attempt since connection fails. On page refresh it creates new connection and reports works.

We are quite helpless at this juncture as we do not know Java and JDBC connector much, but we have encountered above error in which Birt is trying to use a closed connection.

Comment: On which application server is your birt viewer running? Since you mention Apache i assume it is Tomcat but could you confirm

Comment: We are running|using|showing Birt Reports in our application which is running on an Apache [LAMP] server.

Comment: Did you consider using a connection pool in reports? It just requires a small change in your BIRT rpt-design and it would probably fix these connection issues once and for all. Setting up a connection pool with Tomcat, Jboss and Glassfish is easy, i assume it is quite similar with lamp.

Comment: If you are talking about Birt iServer's connection pool configuration then we have set it to default values and also tried disabling it but Birt still  seems to be using the closed connection. Our Birt  iServer is running on a separate server uses Tomcat. We show reports on LAMP based application running on separate server and call reports in HTML code in which report URL is of Birt iServer .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know iServer well enough, but with Eclipse BIRT we need to specify explicitely a connection pool in the datasource of report-designs (property "JNDI url" of a datasource). In my opinion using a connection pool is really crucial in a production context, i am quite confident it would solve these troubles.

Comment: iServer is a part of Birt Tool, it also have connection pool setting but that even does not seem to be working. Our MySQL logs shows following error   every time it closes a connection created by Birt:  [Warning] Aborted connection 7840 to db: 'TestiDB' user: 'test' host: '10.10.23.52' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

Comment: And Birt traces show below error: [Thread 39, birtactuate--2015-02-10 12:18:26--4] 2015-02-10 12:18:26 UTC+0000 org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.Connection.prepareOdaQuery()
SEVERE: Failed to prepare the following query for the data set type (org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.SPSelectDataSet). 
[{call Report_Dashboard_Report(?,?)} ]org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Error preparing SQL statement.
SQL error #1:No operations allowed after connection closed.

Answer (score 1):

It should help others. I also appreciate @Dominique's suggestion of connection pool.

We observed that the native connection pool setting in Birt Management Console were not effective in case when we use mysql-java-connector. Only BirtActuate itself knows why is that.

It all together took a while to solve it out and we tried to solve the issue by creating JNDI data source and Connection Pool in Tomcat configuration files using the solution given [here](http://www.visioneo.org/knowledge-base/-/knowledge_base/article/122720)

Another point worth reading is about [mysqli_real_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) function and the flag MYSQLI_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE which

> Allow interactive_timeout seconds (instead of wait_timeout seconds)
>   of inactivity before closing the connection